# Typescript interface for React HOC Props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Given the following React HOC that adds sorting state to a component:

```
import React, {Component, ComponentClass, ComponentType} from 'react'

interface WithSortState {
    sortOrder: string
}

interface WithSortInjectedProps {
    sortOrder: string
    onSort: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => void
}

const withSort = () => (WrappedComponent: ComponentType<WithSortInjectedProps>): ComponentClass<WithSortInjectedProps> => {
    class WithSort extends Component<WithSortInjectedProps, WithSortState> {

        state = {
            sortOrder: 'created_at_desc'
        };

        handleSort = (sortEvent: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
            this.setState({
                sortOrder: sortEvent.target.value
            })
        };

        render() {
 `           return (
                <WrappedComponent
                    sortOrder={this.state.sortOrder}
                    onSort={this.handleSort}
                    {...this.props}
                />
            )
        }
    }

    return WithSort
};

export default withSort
```

When I manually set the state property `sortOrder` to '123' the compiler complains `sortOrder` is a string. However, if I do the same to the `sortOrder` on the `WrappedComponent` the compiler doesn't throw any errors. For example, `sortOrder={123}` compiles even though the interface indicates that this property should be a string.

Why is this so? Am I doing something wrong on the Typescript side?

Answer (score 1):

It should fail the problem if you try and use sortOrder={123} on the WrappedComponent the reason it doesn't it because you've spread props `{...this.props}` and the props can't be a Partial meaning typescript is smart enough that `sortOrder={123}` will just be overridden with `sortOrder={this.props.sortOrder}`

Hope this helps. TL;DR Remove {...this.props} and all will be revealed

Comment: Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Shanon. It works as expected when removing props spread. However, I don't understand why. `this.props` does not contain a key name `sortOrder` (notice it's coming from the state.) So in my mind, I've indicated the "WrappedComponent" interface should accept a string but it accepts a number as well.